# ¿Cómo puedo generar de inmediato el rfc en un edittext sin seleccionarlo al terminar de ingresar nombre y fecha de nacimiento en Android?

Tags: android

```
do {
            if (etConRFC.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                etConRFC.setText(Util.validRfcCharacters(etConRFCLastName.getText().toString(), etConRFCSecondLastName.getText().toString(),
                        etConRFCName.getText().toString(), etConRFCBirthDate.getText().toString()));

                etConRFC.setSelection(etConRFC.length());
               etConRFC.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ContInfoActivity.this, R.string.toast_load_rfc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }while (!etConRFCLastName.getText().toString().equals("") && !etConRFCName.getText().toString().equals("") && !etConRFCBirthDate.getText().toString().equals(""));
```

[image: Autogenerar rfc en editText]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de la clase **[TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)**, desconozco como formas el RFC pero este es un ejemplo, teniendo 2 editText y un TextView para automaticamente escribir el rfc,

```
         nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
         fecha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);
         rfc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewRFC);
         nombre.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                creaRFC();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        fecha.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                creaRFC();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

cuando cambias el texto en los EditText al mismo tiempo se llama un metodo el cual determina el valor de nombre y fecha y forma el RFC el cual es agregado al TextView.

```
private void creaRFC(){
    String miRFC = nombre.getText().toString() + fecha.getText().toString();
    rfc.setText(miRFC);

}
```

Comment: Gracias !!!!!!!